# SQL - Only show one row per id

Tags: mysql

I need a little help with my sql query. I currently got the following:

```
SELECT dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR, KEK, PREIS, dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ROWID 
FROM dbo.PREISGRUPPEN, dbo.ARTIKEL 
WHERE dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.GRUPPE = 5 AND dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR = dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTIKELNR
ORDER BY dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR, dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ROWID
```

This query gets me the following result:

```
ARTIKELNR   KEK             PREIS   ROWID 
18661840    6.650000000000  4.65    5076049
18661840    6.650000000000  7.44    5448817
18661840    6.650000000000  7.98    5604886
18661841    6.650000000000  4.65    5076050
18661841    6.650000000000  7.44    5448838
18661841    6.650000000000  7.98    5604887
18661842    13.360000000000 9.36    5076051
18661842    13.360000000000 14.96   5448863
18661842    13.360000000000 16.03   5604888
18661843    5.240000000000  7.34    5076052
18661843    5.240000000000  5.87    5448873
18661843    5.240000000000  6.29    5604889
18661844    4.600000000000  6.45    5076053
18661844    4.600000000000  5.15    5448875
18661844    4.600000000000  5.52    5604890
18661845    21.470000000000 25.76   5449243
18661846    6.650000000000  4.65    5076054
18661846    6.650000000000  7.44    5448806
18661846    6.650000000000  7.98    5604891
18661847    6.650000000000  4.65    5076055
18661847    6.650000000000  7.44    5448822
18661847    6.650000000000  7.98    5604892
```

The problem is, I want every ARTIKELNR only once. It should always be the one with the highest ROWID. Basically my result should look like the following table:

```
ARTIKELNR   KEK             PREIS   ROWID 
18661840    6.650000000000  7.98    5604886
18661841    6.650000000000  7.98    5604887
18661842    13.360000000000 16.03   5604888
18661843    5.240000000000  6.29    5604889
18661844    4.600000000000  5.52    5604890
18661845    21.470000000000 25.76   5449243
18661846    6.650000000000  7.98    5604891
18661847    6.650000000000  7.98    5604892
```

How can I solve my problem? I tried Max(ROWID) and nested select queries, but without success. I'm running out of ideas.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe by using `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you were close! Here I used a common table expression (CTE) so I'm working with one table. I then find the `MAX` ROWID for each ARTIKELNR, and then join them back to the CTE to get the rest of the information for the highest ROWID. This will return multiple rows for any ARTIKELNR that has duplicate max ROWIDs. But if ROWID is unique, that won't be a problem.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR, KEK, PREIS, dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ROWID 
    FROM dbo.PREISGRUPPEN, dbo.ARTIKEL 
    WHERE dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.GRUPPE = 5 AND dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR = dbo.ARTIKEL.ARTIKELNR
    ORDER BY dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR, dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ROWID
)

SELECT cte.* 
FROM cte
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ARTIKELNR, MAX(ROWID) AS ROWID
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY ARTIKELNR
) AS A
ON cte.ARTIKELNR = A.ARTIKELNR AND cte.ROWID = A.ROWID
```

Answer (score 1):

use order by  dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ROWID desc and put unique(dbo.PREISGRUPPEN.ARTIKELNR) in first select clause, this should be sufficient.